# Как создать репозиторий на линукс?

Tags: linux, debian, apt

Я собрал deb пакет со своей прогой, нужно как-то ее распространять. Мне нужно чтобы пользователь смог установить мою прогу одной командой `apt install`, может двумя, если нужно добавить репозиторий. Как мне это сделать?

Comment: Смотрел `aptly`?

Comment: Ну вот рекомендую. Он более навороченный, чем, `reprepro` и у него есть api. Даже Майкрософт им пользуется.

Comment: @donRumata напиши ответ, я плюсик поставлю - ну или я может напишу, если руки дойдут.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть проект [aptly](https://www.aptly.info/). Навороченная штука от [Андрея Смирнова](https://www.aptly.info/about/). Умеет делать [зеркала](https://www.aptly.info/doc/aptly/mirror/create/) других реп, создавать [свои](https://www.aptly.info/doc/aptly/repo/create) репы, [снапшоты](https://www.aptly.info/doc/aptly/snapshot/create). Можно работать как через [CLI](https://www.aptly.info/doc/commands), так и через [API](https://www.aptly.info/doc/api).

На Хабре [описан](https://habr.com/ru/post/225825/) опыт использования.

P.S. Даже Майки используют для распространения собственных пакетов. Проверяется в 2 счёта:
`curl --silent http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams/dists/stable/InRelease | grep aptly` выплюнет `Description: Generated by aptly`.

**UPD 1**.
Я таки допишу про создание репы. Итак.

Сначала немного про переменные и конфиги:

`my-first-repo` - имя репозитория для внутренней кухни aptly.

`rolling` - имя релиза бубна\дебиана, которое будет светиться в `sources.list`. Можно сделать такое же как имена дистров, т.е. `bionic`, `buster`, так и чё-то своё. У меня `rolling`, потому что пока нет задачи делать специфичные фишки для конкретного релиза

Конфиг:

```
{
  "rootDir": "/var/aptly",
  "downloadConcurrency": 4,
  "downloadSpeedLimit": 0,
  "architectures": [],
  "dependencyFollowSuggests": false,
  "dependencyFollowRecommends": false,
  "dependencyFollowAllVariants": false,
  "dependencyFollowSource": false,
  "dependencyVerboseResolve": false,
  "gpgDisableSign": false,
  "gpgDisableVerify": false,
  "gpgProvider": "gpg",
  "downloadSourcePackages": false,
  "skipLegacyPool": true,
  "ppaDistributorID": "ubuntu",
  "ppaCodename": "",
  "skipContentsPublishing": false,
  "FileSystemPublishEndpoints": {},
  "S3PublishEndpoints": {},
  "SwiftPublishEndpoints": {}
}
```

`/var/aptly` должен быть создан и туда должен быть ''rw'' доступ.

`Добавление\создание репы != публикация`. При создании репы - создаётся `/var/aptly/pool`, в котором есть вроде бы всё нужное, но это не совсем так. Подробнее - [в документации](https://www.aptly.info/doc/). Когда захотите именно пользоваться готовой штукой как `mirror.yandex.ru`, то надо опубликовать. Тогда в `/var/aptly/public` создаётся дерево, которое уже можно выставлять по http,ftp,etc.

Юнит `systemd`, если вы будете общаться с aptly через http:

```
[Unit]
Description=The Aptly api server
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target

# https://ma.ttias.be/auto-restart-crashed-service-systemd/
StartLimitIntervalSec=500
StartLimitBurst=10

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/aptly api serve -listen=:8080

StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=aptly

User=aptly
Group=aptly

# WorkingDirectory=/var/aptly

# https://ma.ttias.be/auto-restart-crashed-service-systemd/
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

## Создание пустого репозитория:

### Через bash:

```bsh
aptly repo create -distribution="rolling" my-first-repo
```

Публикуем его:

```bsh
aptly -architectures=i386,amd64 publish repo my-first-repo
```

### Через api:

Создаём:

```bsh
curl -X POST \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{"Name":"my-first-repo","DefaultDistribution":"rolling","DefaultComponent":""}' \
http://localhost:8080/api/repos
```

Публикуем:

```bsh
curl -X POST \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{"SourceKind": "local", "Sources": [{"Name": "my-first-repo"}], "Architectures": ["i386", "amd64"], "Distribution": "rolling"}' \
http://localhost:8080/api/publish
```

### Через Ansible:

Переменные:

```yaml
aptly_my_first_repo_name: my-first-repo

aptly_my_first_repo_distribution: rolling

aptly_api_port: 8080
```

```yaml
- name: Create my first repo
  uri:
    url: http://localhost:{{ aptly_api_port }}/api/repos
    method: POST
    body_format: json
    body:
      Name: "{{ aptly_my_first_repo_name }}"
      DefaultDistribution: "{{ aptly_my_first_repo_distribution }}"
    status_code:
      - 201
      - 400
  tags:
    - api
    - repo
    - create
```

```yaml
- name: Publish my first repo
  uri:
    url: http://localhost:{{ aptly_api_port }}/api/repos
    method: POST
    body_format: json
    body:
      SourceKind: "local"
      Sources: 
        - Name: "{{ aptly_my_first_repo_name }}"
      Architectures:
        - i386
        - amd64
      Distribution: "{{ aptly_my_first_repo_distribution }}"
    status_code:
      - 200
      - 201
      - 400
  tags:
    - api
    - repo
    - publish
```

## Как всё выглядит после создания пустого репозитория

### Через api

```bsh
curl --silent http://localhost:8080/api/repos | jq .
```

```
[
  {
    "Name": "my-first-repo",
    "DefaultDistribution": "rolling",
    "DefaultComponent": "main"
  }
]
```

### Через bash

```bsh
sudo aptly repo list -raw
```

```
my-first-repo
```

```bsh
sudo aptly publish list -raw
```

```
. rolling
```

### Через ФС

```bsh
cd /var/aptly/public
```

```bsh
.
├── dists
│   └── rolling
│       ├── InRelease
│       ├── main
│       │   ├── binary-amd64
│       │   │   ├── Packages
│       │   │   ├── Packages.bz2
│       │   │   ├── Packages.gz
│       │   │   └── Release
│       │   └── binary-i386
│       │       ├── Packages
│       │       ├── Packages.bz2
│       │       ├── Packages.gz
│       │       └── Release
│       ├── Release
│       └── Release.gpg
├── pool
├── repo.key
└── repo.key.gpg
```

## Добавление пакета

```bsh
cd /var/aptly/upload && wget https://download.cdn.viber.com/cdn/desktop/Linux/viber.deb
```

### Через bash

Добавляем пакет:

```bsh
aptly repo add my-first-repo /var/aptly/upload/viber.deb
```

Публикуем:

```bsh
aptly publish update rolling
```

### Через api\ansible

```yaml
- name: Add Viber to repo over api
  when:
    - ansible_os_family == 'Debian'
    - ansible_pkg_mgr == 'apt'
    - aptly_add_first_software_in_created_repo_over == 'api'
  uri:
    url: http://localhost:{{ aptly_api_port }}/api/repos/{{ aptly_my_first_repo_name }}/file/viber.deb
    method: POST
    status_code:
      - 200
      - 201
      - 400
```

```yaml
- name: Update published repo over api
  when:
    - ansible_os_family == 'Debian'
    - ansible_pkg_mgr == 'apt'
    - aptly_add_first_software_in_created_repo_over == 'api'
  uri:
    url: http://localhost:{{ aptly_api_port }}/api/publish/:./{{ aptly_my_first_repo_distribution }}
    method: PUT
    body_format: json
    body:
      SourceKind: "local"
      # Sources: [{"Name": "{{ aptly_my_first_repo_name }}"}]
      Sources:
        - Name: "{{ aptly_my_first_repo_name }}"
          Component: "{{ aptly_my_first_repo_component }}"
      Architectures:
        - i386
        - amd64
      Distribution: "{{ aptly_my_first_repo_distribution }}"
    status_code:
      - 200
      - 201
      - 400
```

Вообще, написана и оттестирована [роль для ansible](https://github.com/don-rumata/ansible-role-install-aptly) и всё выдернуто оттуда, если что

Comment: Чтоб это было ответом на вопрос - нужно скопипастить сюда команды **как создать репу** и **как добавить в неё пакет**, можно про подпись добавить потому как apt не любит неподписанные репы и не будет с неё обновляться в автоматическом режиме

Comment: классный ответ!

Answer (score 13):

```
apt-get install reprepro gnupg2

mkdir /var/www/debian
mkdir /var/www/debian/conf

touch /var/www/debian/conf/distributions
editor /var/www/debian/conf/distributions
```

Там пишем описание репозитория

```
Codename:  stable
Suite:  stable
Version: 1.x
Origin: Nikolaich
Label: Nikolaich
Description: Nikolaich Stable Repository
Architectures: amd64
Components: main
SignWith: default
DebIndices: Packages Release . .gz .bz2
DscIndices: Sources Release . .gz .bz2
Contents: . .gz .bz2
```

дальше

```
cd /var/www/debian
gpg --gen-key
gpg --armor --export > repokey.asc
```

Там будет айди ключа, типа 4607CAF2F88913A6
Его добавить в файл выше.

```
SignWith: 4607CAF2F88913A6
```

Дальше создаем саму репу

```
cd /var/www/debian

reprepro export
reprepro createsymlinks
```

И заливаем пакет

```
reprepro --priority optional --section drivers includedeb  stable /root/mysuper.deb
```

Потом настраиваем вэб-сервер, чтоб папка debian была доступна через http://example.com/debian/

Устанавливается в для клиентов в пару команд:

```
wget -O- http://example.com/debian/repokey.asc | apt-key add -
echo "deb http://example.com/debian stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/myrepo.list
apt update
```

[похожая инструкция на debian.org](https://wiki.debian.org/ru/CreateLocalRepo#C_.2BBD8EPgQ8BD4ESQRMBE4_.2BBEMEQgQ4BDsEOARCBEs__reprepro)